# RestKit crashing at RKEntityMapping line

Tags: ios, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am new to Objective-C and very stuck with RestKit. I am trying to create a very simple `UITableView` with data from JSON on my web server and I have been stuck for a while.

This is my simple JSON:

```
{
    "restaurants": [
        {
            "id": "27",
            "franchise_name": "Franchise 1",
            "branch_name": "Branch 1",
            "branch_phone": "0200 111 0000",
            "cuisine": "Salad",
            "cooking_time": "15",
            "is_open": 1
        },
        {
            "id": "97",
            "franchise_name": "Franchise 2",
            "branch_name": "Branch 2",
            "branch_phone": "0207 222 0000",
            "cuisine": "Healthy",
            "cooking_time": "10",
            "is_open": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my Core Data model:

```
    Entities: Restaurant
    Attributes: branchName -> String
    franchiseName -> String
    id -> integer 16
    readyTime-> integer 16
```

I have the following code in my view controller. In `viewDidLoad`, `RKEntityMapping` causes an exception:

```
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore];

RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Restaurant" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore]; //THIS LINE CAUSES THE CRASH

[entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                    @"id":             @"id",
                                                    @"cooking_time":   @"readyTime",
                                                    @"branch_name":    @"branchName",
                                                    @"franchise_name": @"franchiseName"}];

RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMapping pathPattern:@"/api/restaurants" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]; //I GET AN ISSUE HERE AS WELL INVOLVING responseDescriptorWithMapping BEING DEPRECIATED.

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http//mywebserver.com/api/resturants"]];

RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *managedObjectRequestOperation = [[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[ responseDescriptor ]];

managedObjectRequestOperation.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

[[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] addOperation:managedObjectRequestOperation];
```

There are several error messages none of which I really get:

```
    NSAssert(objectClass, @"Cannot initialize an entity mapping for an entity with a nil managed object class: Got nil class for managed object class name '%@'. Maybe you forgot to add the class files to your target?", [entity managedObjectClassName]);
```

In the console:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[RKEntityMapping initWithEntity:],
```

Answer (score 0):

`responseDescriptorWithMapping` is deprecated, it now has an extra `method` parameter. This is just a warning - you should update but you don't have to.

If the crash happens when you try to use the `managedObjectStore` for the first time it would suggest that you haven't properly / fully configured your Core Data stack (or that your entity name / class name is wrong). Check [this doc](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#managed-object-request) for a simple overview of what setup is required. If you want to use an object manager, check [this doc](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#configure-core-data-integration-with-the-object-manager).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mind giving me a bit more detail on the second part. I am new to this and I was following the Gist tutorial that does not seem to require all that extra code.

Comment: Which tutorial (give a link). You need to create the managed object store and contexts as an absolute minimum.

Comment: It's the one from the github wiki

Comment: This section https://github.com/RestKit/RKGist/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#configuring-restkit--core-data shows the required setup.

Comment: This is what I don't get. I have done exactly that (only difference is that my pathForResource is different and I put the file name of my xcdatamodel).

Comment: I really appreciate your help by the way I have been on this for four days now.

Comment: Did you debug to check for errors and that everything was created ?

Comment: Yea as far as I can tell there are no errors before the line I have highlighted. I see you are London based by the way. If you are near google campus (old street circle) I can show you the code.

Comment: Not close. You checked the store and context were created? Try running a fetch on the context and creating (and saving) some objects in a bit of test code.